# What does congruency mean in $D_4$?

Tags: group-theory, congruences, dihedral-groups

What does congruency mean in $D_4$?

How can I check for example that

For $K = \{k_0, k_2\}$,
$$p_x \equiv p_y \pmod K$$

I.e. how to evaluate $(p_x - p_y) \bmod K$, specifically what is $(p_x - p_y)$?

---

$k_0$ is a rotation of $0$°.
$k_2$ is a rotation of $180$°.
$p_x$ is the horizontal (x-axis) flip.
$p_y$ is the vertical (y-axis) flip.

Comment: what you really mean is $p_xp_y^{-1}$ because $p_x-p_y$  means nothing at $D_4$

Comment: @janmarqz And why is that equivalent to $p_x - p_y$, or is it just an alternative definition?

Comment: for the group $D_4$ it is used multiplication or juxtaposition, but not subtraction

Answer (score 1):

$K$ is a subgroup of $D_4$, and $p_x\equiv p_y\pmod K$ means $\bar{p_x}=\bar{p_y}$ in $D_4/K$. Actually $p_y=p_xk_2$.

Comment: What does  $\bar{p_x}=\bar{p_y}$ mean? Specifically \bar{}?

Comment: It means a equivalent class: $\bar{p_x}=p_x\cdot K=\{p_xk_0, p_xk_2\}$.